# Proving non-convexity of a set of lattice points

Tags: co.combinatorics, combinatorial-geometry

I have a set of lattice points S in R^n (listed in memory in a computer for n=8 say). I want to computationally certify that they do *not* form the lattice points of a convex polytope P in R^n. (Ex. S={-1,1} in R^1.) Is there an easy (and hopefully efficient enough) way to do this?

Remarks:

- I don't have much feel for the (many) points themselves at the moment. For instance, I don't know what are vertices of the convex hull of S (or how to find that).
- Assuming I could find a description of the convex hull, I get scared about a solution that says "now figure out what the lattice points are and compare with S", because of efficiency concerns.

Thank you!

Comment: the procedure I suggest does not enumerate points, it only counts them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compute the convex hull $P$ of these points, and then apply, say, [Barvinok's algorithm](http://math.uchicago.edu/~shmuel/AAT-readings/Combinatorial%20Geometry,%20Concentration,%20Real%20Algebraic%20Geometry/barvinok%20MSRI.pdf) for counting $|P\cap\mathbb{Z}^n|$. Comparing the latter with $|S|$ would give you the needed certificate. Although $n=8$ might be a bit too high for an existing implementation (e.g. [LattE](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~latte/)) to handle.

Another trick might be to compute the volume of $P$ - it will give you some bound on the number of integer vectors in $P$.

On can use [Sage](http://sagemath.org) to compute the convex hull etc (note that it does not do integer points count efficiently, though). Here is a toy example:

`l=LatticePolytope([[2,0],[0,2],[1,1]],compute_vertices=True); l; l.npoints()`

`A lattice polytope: 1-dimensional, 2 vertices.`

`3`

Comment: Hi (and thanks) -- I was afraid of that answer. Actually, how does one go about actually obtaining a description of the convex hull of S?

Comment: Two primary options for computing hulls in higher dimensions are [Qhull](http://www.qhull.org/) and [CGAL](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/packages.html#Part:ConvexHullAlgorithms). Both require considerable study before you can use them.

Comment: @Joseph O'Rourke -- I looked a little at CGAL's manual which gave an idea. I want to take any two points x and y of S and show that any lattice point on the line xy is in S. This is a horrid, worse than |S| choose 2 algorithm but might be a quick enough (albeit dirty) way to just check (non)convexity. Is there any problem with that?

Comment: one can use Sage to compute the convex hull. It can even be done online, without installing Sage on a local machine, using e.g. http://cloud.sagemath.org

Comment: e.g. here is a toy example using Sage:
l=LatticePolytope([[2,0],[0,2],[1,1]],compute_vertices=True); l; l.npoints()

it will output
A lattice polytope: 1-dimensional, 2 vertices.
3

Answer (score 2):

To respond to your suggestion in your comment to Dima's answer:
This set $S$ of four points in $\mathbb{Z}^2$
does
"not form the lattice points of a convex polytope,"
and yet, for
"any two points $x$ and $y$ of $S$," every "lattice point on the line [segment] $xy$ is in $S$":

          [image: Lattice4Pts]